# After doing brush I feel hungry?

Tags: human-biology, teeth, saliva

Why I feel hungry after brushing my teeth in morning?

I usually have my dinner in between 9 to 10 at night and then I sleep at 12. Sometimes I wake up at 6 in morning and then I go to brush my teeth. After brushing my teeth I feel hungry. Why I feel hungry after brushing my teeth? And this hunger is gone even if I take few(about 5-10) biscuits.

Now one day I woke up at 6 am and then I have not brushed my teeth till 11 am and on this day I was not feeling hungry till 10 am.

So is there any chemical in toothpaste which triggers hunger? One thing which I can notice is that before doing brush there is saliva in mouth whereas just after doing brush there is no saliva or very less amount of saliva in mouth.

Even after chewing a gum for 30  min I feel the same hunger. So is there any relation between toothpaste and chewing gum?

Comment: Correlation does not imply causation. Furthermore, you have presented an anecdotal claim. Do you have any evidence this is a widely experienced event?

Comment: @Singh try to keep anecdotal experiences out of the questions - only if its a widely held belief or experience should you be asking the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your daily pattern has made your brain associate brushing your teeth as a precursor of your breakfast. Skipping this step will confuse your brain into thinking it's not time for breakfast yet. Same goes for chewing gum, the toothpaste smell will trigger your brain's association of brushing teeth with the breakfast to come.

Comment: Sir I think you are right because when I was in school then my school timing was from 7 am to 12:30 pm but always I wake up at 6 am and after that I brush take bath then I get dressed and take my breakfast and then go to school. So the time in between my brushing and my breakfast is small and so I think you are correct. Thanks for your answer.